# LotusScript get attachment's position and replace it

Tags: lotus, lotusscript

I have a Notes application, with a form. On the form I have a richtext field.
I have to remove all of the attachments and replace them with a picture in the rt field.

So far I have a "demo" app, which removes the attachments and replace them with the picture (I'm using NotesRichTextNavigator), but I can't save / restore their position.

Is there any way to do that ?

It's working, but this way I cannot set the NotesEmbeddedObject position in the rt field :

```
Set rtItem=doc.GetFirstItem(rtField)
Call rtitem.EmbedObject ( EMBED_ATTACHMENT, "", filePath)
Call doc.Save( True, False )
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really have to keep the position of the attachment then look at `NotesDXLExporter` and `NotesDXLImporter`. Export the document as DXL, replace attachments with the pictures in DXL and import it back to a document. Make sure that you use `notesDXLExporter.RichTextOption=RICHTEXTOPTION_DXL`

Comment: Unfortunately DXLExporter / Importer isn't an acceptable way. Is there any other way ? Replace manually the $FILE field etc. ... ?

Comment: Why is DXLExporter/Importer not acceptable for you or your application? An alternative is using the commercial product MidasLSX http://www.geniisoft.com/showcase.nsf/MidasLSX.

Comment: Unfortunately my company doesn't want to use DXLImporter, because they've had a very bad experiences with this method, for example : "Dxl importer operation failed" errors.
Our application processes e-mail messages: if the message contains attachments the app has to replace all of them with another object. During the process we have to preserve the attachment's position. Thx for MidasLSX !

Comment: I understand although I've had really good experience with DXLIm-/Exporter. I used it for replacements of "variables" in RichText. I worked with in memory DXL streams and never wrote DXL to a file.

Comment: Thank you, I give it a try.